# How to open telephone app in iOS without any number

Tags: ios

I wanted to open a telephone app (dialer app) in iOS without any number. 
please let me know how to achieve this.

Thanks.

Comment: **It is not possible** you need to use telPrompt with compulsory  number !!!

Comment: Is it possible to open the contacts app atleast ?